# Laravel Passing variable not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

Hello People here is my code i have used in controller...

```
public function bulk()
{
    return View::make('bulk')->with('message','hii there');

}
```

my route file contains...

```
Route::get('bulk',array('uses'=>'HomeController@bulk'))->before('auth');
```

In my view Iam testing it by ...

```
@if(Session::has('message')) 
Present
@else
not Present
@endif
```

The page is making a view with the message 'not Present' why is it??
I even tried

```
return Redirect::to('bulk')->with('message','hii there');
```

I get an erro mesage on Console

```
 mypro/public/bulk net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What could be the problem?? is there any issues with name?? I tried this method earlier which worked fine for me.... :(

Iam using Blade Template..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing `Redirect` and `View`. You use `Session::get` to access variables passed to *redirects*. For views (as in your case), `with` will pass an simple PHP variable into your view. So your check should be:

```
@if(isset($message)) 
  {{{ $message }}}
@else
  No message!
@endif
```

[Read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/responses)

Comment: Use `{{{ $message }}}` to echo blade data (or `{{ $message }}` to not escape). [Read more here](http://laravel.com/docs/templates)

Comment: Great it seems to be working, But in my other pages i have used `@if(Session::has('message')) ` :( any ways thanks dear...

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, you need to access the "with" value in the view using a PHP variable, it's not passed via the session.  In your case, that would be `$message`.  If you want to use the session, you should use `Session::flash()` or `Session::put()`.

Comment: Iam using blade template... my view file is `bulk.blade.php` ...let me try u r suggestion...